# org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to instantiate components

Tags: java, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

When I try to start my server (Karaf 7.2.0), I get the below error message-

```
2021-06-28 08:20:03,806 | ERROR | FelixStartLevel      | o.a.a.b.c.BlueprintContainerImpl | 58 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.9.0 | Unable to start blueprint container for bundle MyWorkflow/1.0-SNAPSHOT
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to instantiate components
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:720) ~[58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:413) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:278) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:299) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:268) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:264) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:254) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422) [58:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.9.0]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1179) [?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:730) [?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:485) [?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4579) [?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2174) [?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1373) [?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/camel/component/jms/JmsComponent
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2410) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2194) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1607) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1927) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.loadClass(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:450) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.loadClass(BlueprintRepository.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.GenericType.parse(GenericType.java:135) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.doLoadType(AbstractRecipe.java:169) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.loadType(AbstractRecipe.java:162) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.loadClass(BeanRecipe.java:251) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getType(BeanRecipe.java:772) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromType(BeanRecipe.java:342) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:283) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:685) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:666) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:90) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:360) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:190) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:716) ~[?:?]
    ... 19 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent not found by MyWorkflow [16]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1639) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2410) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2194) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1607) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2053) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1927) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.loadClass(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:450) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.loadClass(BlueprintRepository.java:524) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.GenericType.parse(GenericType.java:135) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.doLoadType(AbstractRecipe.java:169) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.loadType(AbstractRecipe.java:162) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.loadClass(BeanRecipe.java:251) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getType(BeanRecipe.java:772) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstanceFromType(BeanRecipe.java:342) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:283) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:685) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:666) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:81) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:90) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:360) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:190) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:716) ~[?:?]
    ... 19 more
```

Now, I have tried adding the `camel-jms` jar as a dependency in my `pom.xml` file, but that wasn't of any use.

I also deleted the contents of `%KARAF_HOME%\data\tmp` and `%KARAF_HOME%\data\cache`, but I'm guessing I'm not supposed to do that.

Since I'm new to this, any help would be appreciated. Do let me know if more info is needed to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this :-

1. Delete tmp file
2. Delete cache file.
3. Then restart your server.